# connect socketIO with options in swift

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io

I am trying to use socketIO for one of my projects.
I need to use following options while connecting to my socketIO server.

```
let socketConfig = SocketIOClientOption.self
socketConfig.forceNew(true)
socketConfig.reconnects(true)
socketConfig.reconnectAttempts(10)
socketConfig.reconnectWait(6000)
```

According to socketIO docs (https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift) I am not able to find a way to pass SocketIOOptions while connecting.
I have been trying to use below code to connect but it fails due to the absence of these options

```
let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "myurl:9476")!, config: [.log(true), .connectParams(["key":"value"])])
let socket = manager.defaultSocket
```

SocketIO version used:- 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift', '~> 13.3.0'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the solution.
The way to include options has been revised in the latest version.
I did the following and it worked:-

```
manager  = SocketManager(socketURL:  URL(string:"myurl:123")!, config: [.log(true), .forceNew(true), .reconnectAttempts(10), .reconnectWait(6000), .connectParams(["key":"value"]), .forceWebsockets(true), .compress])
socket = manager?.defaultSocket
```

Comment: my class should be singleton to work? without being singleton it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Socket singleton class in Swift 4

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire
import SocketIO
import ObjectMapper

typealias  OrderEventResponseBlock = (_ response : Any? , _ type : OrderEventType) -> ()
typealias  TrackResponseBlock = (_ response : Any?) -> ()

class SocketIOManager: NSObject {

    static let shared = SocketIOManager()
    private var manager: SocketManager?
    var socket: SocketIOClient?

    override init() {
        super.init()

        let token = UDSingleton.shared.userData?.userDetails?.accessToken
        guard let URL = URL(string: APIBasePath.basePath) else {return}
        manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL , config: [.log(true), .connectParams(["access_token" : /token])])
        socket = manager?.defaultSocket
        setupListeners()

    }

    //Server Methods

    func establishConnection() {

        let token = UDSingleton.shared.userData?.userDetails?.accessToken
        if (self.socket?.status == .disconnected || self.socket?.status == .notConnected ) {
            if (token != nil || token != "") {
                socket?.connect()
            }
        }
        else {
            debugPrint("======= Socket already connected =======")
        }
    }

    func closeConnection() {
        debugPrint("=======***** SocketClientEvent.disconnect called ****=======")
        socket?.disconnect()
    }

    func setupListeners() {

        socket?.on(SocketClientEvent.disconnect.rawValue) { [weak self] (array, emitter) in
            debugPrint("======= SocketClientEvent.disconnect listener=======")
          self?.establishConnection()
        }

        socket?.on(SocketClientEvent.error.rawValue) {[weak self] (array, emitter) in
            debugPrint("======= SocketClientEvent.error =======")
          self?.establishConnection()
        }

        socket?.on(SocketClientEvent.connect.rawValue) {  (array, emitter) in
            if self.socket?.status == .connected {
                debugPrint("======= userauth after connected =======")
            }
        }
    }


    func getStatus() -> SocketIOStatus? {
        guard let status = self.socket?.status else{ return nil }
        return status
    }



    //MARK:- Listening Events
    //MARK:-

    func listenOrderEventConnected(_ completionHandler: @escaping OrderEventResponseBlock) {
        socket?.on(SocketEvents.OrderEvent.rawValue) {(arrData, socketAck) in

            guard let item = JSON(arrData[0]).dictionaryObject else {return}

            guard  let type = item["type"] as? String else{return}

            guard let typeSocket :  OrderEventType = OrderEventType(rawValue: type) else {return}

           }
        }


    //MARK:- EmitterWithAcknowledge Events

    func emitMapLocation(_ userData : [String: Any] , _ completionHandler: @escaping TrackResponseBlock) {

        socket?.emitWithAck(SocketEvents.CommonEvent.rawValue , userData).timingOut(after: 4.0, callback: { (response) in
            guard  let item = JSON(response[0]).dictionaryObject else{return}
            let json = JSON(item)
             if json[APIConstants.statusCode.rawValue].stringValue == Validate.successCode.rawValue {
                 let objDriver = Mapper<ApiSucessData<DriverList>>().map(JSONObject: item)
              completionHandler( objDriver?.object)

             }
        })
    }


    func getParticularOrder(_ userData : [String: Any]  , _ completionHandler: @escaping TrackResponseBlock) {

        socket?.emitWithAck(SocketEvents.CommonEvent.rawValue, userData).timingOut(after: 2.0, callback: { (response) in
            let item = JSON(response[0]).dictionaryObject

            let json = JSON(item)

            if json[APIConstants.statusCode.rawValue].stringValue == Validate.successCode.rawValue {
                let objOrder = Mapper<ApiSucessData<Order>>().map(JSONObject: item)
                completionHandler( objOrder?.object)
            }
        })
    }


}
```

Comment: my class should be singleton to work? without being singleton it doesn't work?